# how to find tail of a file using c code

Tags: c, file

I wrote code to find the tail, but, it has one exception, when I am trying to print whole lines as a tail, it will not print the starting character.
for e.g. if my file is having 14 lines, and the value of `n` I entered is also 14, then it will not print the starting character.

Please just help to modify my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    FILE *in, *out;
    int count = 0,lines;
    long int pos;
    char s[100];
    char ch,c;
    if(argc<2)
    {
        printf("Arguments which is to be passed should be 2");
    }
    else if(argc>2)
    {
        printf("too many argumnets are passed");
    }
    in = fopen("anj.txt", "r");
    out = fopen("output.txt", "w");
    if(in==NULL || out==NULL)
    {
        printf("unable to open");
        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        int n=atoi(argv[1]);
        if(n>=1)
        {
            fseek(in, 0, SEEK_END);
            pos = ftell(in);
            while (pos)
            {
                fseek(in, --pos, SEEK_SET);
                if (fgetc(in) == '\n')
                {
                    //count=count+1;
                    if (count++==n)
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(count<n)
            {
                printf("no. of lines in file %d is less than enterd",count);
            }
            c = fgetc(in);
            while (c != EOF)
            {
                fputc(c, out);
                c = fgetc(in);
            }
        }
        else
        printf("renter the value of n");
    }
    fclose(in);
    fclose(out);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem with you spacebar when trying to indent the code?

Comment: @Trisha you can use `getline` you know!

Comment: getline() is not portable. It's Posix, not standard C.  But you can easily write your own function to do the same thing that is.

Comment: see when pos == 1 , fseek set to 0 but fgetc(in) is called then your position in file is at 1 again when while exits. that's why.

Answer (score 1):

If the number of lines is the same as the entered value, your code will read the first char in the file, consume it by fgetc, and end the loop due to `pos == 0`!

Add this check just after the while loop for this corner case:

```
if (pos == 0)
{
    fseek(in, 0, SEEK_SET);
}
```

Comment: this is the precise answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

If by *tail* you mean the *last line* of a file, there is a much easier way to get the last line of the file, and write it to the output file using fgets()`:

```
int CountLines(FILE *fp);

int main(void)
{
    FILE *in, *out;
    char string[509];
    char input[80];
    char *dummy;
    char *fmt = "%[^\n]%*c";
    int count=0;
    int index = 0;
    int tailCnt=0;

    in = fopen("anj.txt", "r");
    out = fopen("output.txt", "w");
    if(in==NULL || out==NULL)
    {
        printf("unable to open");
        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        //get count of lines
        tailCnt = -1;
        count = CountLines(in);
        rewind (in);
        while((tailCnt<=0) || (tailCnt > count))
        {
            printf("File has %d lines.\nEnter lines from bottom of file to output (1 to %d).\n", count, count);

            scanf(fmt, input);
            tailCnt = strtol(input, &dummy, 10);
        }
        while(fgets(string, 100, in)) 
        {
            if(index >= (count-tailCnt))
            {
                fputs(string, out);
            }
            index++;

        }
        //check for fgets() error
        if(errno != 0)
        {
             printf("Error returned from fgets().  Exiting\n");
             return 0;
        }
    }
    fclose(in);
    fclose(out);
    return 0;
}

int CountLines(FILE *fp)//simple example line count, 
{                       //no error checking...
    int count=0;
    char line[509] = {0};//ANSI compatibility requires a compiler to accept minimum of 509 characters

    while(fgets(line, 509, fp)) count++;

    return count;

}
```

Tested for corner cases 0, 1 and 17 for following *anj.txt*:

```
This is line 1
This is line 2
This is line 3
This is line 4
This is line 5
This is line 6
This is line 7
This is line 8
This is line 9
This is line 10
This is line 11
This is line 12
This is line 13
This is line 14
This is line 15
This is line 16
This is line 17
```

Comment: no actualy i want to print last n no. of lines of file;n should be entered by user only. actually yes your method seems easy can you modify it to print last n no. of lines.

Comment: @Trisha - _can you modify it to print last n no. of lines_...  Yes.  This prompts the user for a number of lines, and does not accept zero, or a number greater than the count of lines in the file.